# Remote debug from intellij and jdb but not eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

This is on linux, with jdk1.8 and latest Eclipse/Oxygen.  I just get connection refused when debugging from eclipse.  I am using socket-attach / localhost / 6666 as my remote config.

I used the example from here: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-remote-debug-with-eclipse/

Here's my command line:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=6666 com.javapapers.java.DebugRemote
```

I can attach and debug from both jdb and intellij, but not eclipse (using latest oxygen release).

eg:  jdb -attach 6666 works fine (I can execute threads command)

Anyone know what might be the issue?  Is there an iptables command I can run to debug this?

One thing I noticed is that after getting connection refused in eclipse, I can no longer attach from Intellij.  I have to restart the process.  That being said, in intellij or jdb I can attach/re-attach as much as I want.

There are no firewall entries for eclipse that I can see causing this.

I'm trying to connect to localhost.  I've tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, the host IP address. I have tried everything.

Edit:

Update:

sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -A -n "src port 6666 or dst port 6666"

reports traffic for jdb but not eclipse.  But after trying to connect via eclipse, I can no longer connect via jdb.  ARP isn't reporting anything weird either.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Same here. Able to attach from jdb and netbeans but not from eclipse (various releases - photon, kepler, neon, Nov-19). Need to try with ganymede!